# Process SQL return into JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm playing with building my first JSON API here. I have the following function that returns JSON from my SQL query:

```
function processResponse($response)
{
      // if (!$key) echo '[';
      for ($i=0;$i<count($response);$i++) {
        echo ($i>0?',':'').json_encode($response);
      }
      // if (!$key) echo ']';
}
```

Notice I have commented the opening and closing `[ ]` brackets as I was noticing multiple (unnecessary) nested arrays. This allows something like this: `$json[0]->email;` otherwise it would be a nested array and I would need to do something like `$json[0][0]->email;`

However, when I do a `json_decode()` on my processed output I get a null. Adding a `[]` back resolves this.

So I guess my question is why does `json_decode()` return `null` for this:

```
[{"inventory_id":7,"start":null,"expiration":null,"created":"2016-12-05 10:58:23","updated":"2016-12-08 15:29:56","item_name":"Tour Ticket (Per Person)","default_rate":null,"quantity":5,"bookings_count":"6","itinerary_count":"8","group_name":"Winery","location_name":"Location 1","status":"Active","type_name":"Tour","username":"email@address.com","user_id":4},{"inventory_id":20,"start":null,"expiration":null,"created":"2016-12-06 12:33:18","updated":"2016-12-08 15:41:12","item_name":"Tasting Ticket","default_rate":null,"quantity":10,"bookings_count":"0","itinerary_count":"0","group_name":"Winery","location_name":"Location 1","status":"Archived","type_name":"Ticket","username":"email@address.com","user_id":4}]
```

and why does this work:

```
[[{"inventory_id":7,"start":null,"expiration":null,"created":"2016-12-05 10:58:23","updated":"2016-12-08 15:29:56","item_name":"Tour Ticket (Per Person)","default_rate":null,"quantity":5,"bookings_count":"6","itinerary_count":"8","group_name":"Winery","location_name":"Location 1","status":"Active","type_name":"Tour","username":"email@address.com","user_id":4},{"inventory_id":20,"start":null,"expiration":null,"created":"2016-12-06 12:33:18","updated":"2016-12-08 15:41:12","item_name":"Tasting Ticket","default_rate":null,"quantity":10,"bookings_count":"0","itinerary_count":"0","group_name":"Winery","location_name":"Location 1","status":"Archived","type_name":"Ticket","username":"email@address.com","user_id":4}]]
```

Is there a better way for me to construct the JSON output?

Comment: Don't use `json_encode()` on elements and stick them together manually; build your full response as PHP objects and `json_encode()` the whole thing.

Comment: Throw the function away and just do `echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: huh, simple... i was using this as a reference to build my API: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/ I wonder why they would construct the JSON in this way?

Comment: It's because they're encoding and appending query results as they fetch them. They can't JSON encode it all at once because it's not all there yet.

Comment: The only explanation for doing it the way they're doing it is that they're worried about using too much memory if they load all the results into an array. But it's generally a poor way to do it.

Comment: The reason you're getting nested arrays is because you're doing `json_encode($response)` instead of `json_encode($response[$i])`. You're repeatedly encoding the whole array instead of the current element of the loop.'

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess that article got me on the wrong track. Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 0):

You only need return your data from db as an associative array then you call `json_encode` and you will be happy to go. it does all the work for you.

```
$data = ["name" => "john doe", "age" : 33];
print json_enconde($data); // {"name" : "john doe", "age": 33 }

$data = [
    ["name" => "john doe", "age" : 33],
    ["name" => "mary doe", "age" : 28]
];
print json_enconde($data); // [{"name" : "john doe", "age": 33 }, {"name" : "mary doe", "age": 28 }]
```

As you can see... $data only need to be an associative array, so fetch as it from your db

Be aware that sometimes your data don't fit UTF8 to be parsed to json. this is specially true when you are retuning blobs from your db.

I really recomend you to read this

http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP/